# Guid attribute returns wrong value when try to get it via Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

This is how I extract elements but when I try to get value of attribute I get just some number instead of Guid string:

```
... = from c in xdoc.Element(mdpr + "A")
                    .Elements(mdpr + "B")
                    .Elements(mdpr + "C")
      let data= c                                   
      select new MyData
      {
          state = (string)data.Element(mdpr + "state"),
          TEMP = (string)data.Attribute("guidNumber") // TEMP is string
...
```

This is XML:

```
...
<mdpr:B>
    <mdpr:C guidNumber="4t56u27b-b784-4303-b710-95966b6e68ba" >
      <mdpr:state>17</mdpr:state>
...
```

**UPDATE**

If XML has '{' then it works:

```
 <mdpr:C guidNumber="4t56u27b-b784-4303-b710-95966b6e68ba" > // doesn't work
 <mdpr:C guidNumber="{4t56u27b-b784-4303-b710-95966b6e68ba}" > // work
```

But how to get this value then?

Comment: You do realize it's an invalid GUID string? It contains a `t`, which is not a hexadecimal character

Comment: no I have changed it for question here Guid is valid but '{' cause a problem to get it's values.

Answer (score 0):

you want the [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value.aspx) of the attribute:

`data.Attribute("guidNumber").Value`

Comment: No, that doesn't return Guid string too. I get just some number 000005 which doesn't exist in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet below works to be fine:

```
String xml_string = @"<root xmlns:mdpr=""someUri"">
                          <mdpr:A>
                              <mdpr:B>
                              <mdpr:C guidNumber=""4t56u27b-b784-4303-b710-95966b6e68ba"" >
                                <mdpr:state>17</mdpr:state>
                              </mdpr:C>
                              </mdpr:B>
                          </mdpr:A>
                      </root>";

var q = XElement.Parse(xml_string).Descendants()
          .Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == "C").First()
          .Attribute("guidNumber").Value;

Console.WriteLine(q);
```